# .htaccess rewrite based on browser language apply only once

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following rewrite rules to redirect a visitor to the correct language page:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/[L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /fr/[L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /es/[L,R=301]
```

This code works fine but has a drawback.

The site is Dutch by default and hasn't a specific directory to point to except for the root domain.

If you're Dutch but your browser language is setup to be English you will be redirected to root.com/en/ which is expected behaviour.

However the site has three language links to point you to the other translations of that page. These links are all working fine except the one linking to the root domain (the Dutch homepage)

The link to the Dutch homepage keeps redirecting you to the /en/ when you're browser language is set to English.

This only happens at the homepage which is obvious. However it there a way to apply these rewrite rules only once so you can override the redirect if you want to?

With the current setup you can never reach the homepage / root domain after being redirected.

Thanks.

Comment: No, since none of those requests have any connection to each other, you can not do anything “only once” on that level - at least not with the information you are evaluating right now. You could of course try and set a cookie on the first visit - so that you can then check for that on your next round of rewriting. But this will of course fail for users who don’t accept cookies, plus if f.e. a search engine was requesting a specific language, but didn’t bother with cookies, you’d have a problem in that regard, too.

Comment: Might make more sense perhaps if you appended something to the URL, from the place where you link back to the Dutch version, that you can check against - something like `http://example.com/?noredirect`